# table is not generated after rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, elasticsearch

I have one csv file with bunch of data when I use rake db:seed command 
console shows..

```
deleting old index
creating new index
starting import
20
refresh index
```

look like every thing fine but table not even created

my seed.rb is

```
require 'csv'

puts "deleting old index"
Article.index.delete

puts "creating new index"
Article.create_elasticsearch_index

mapping = {
"id" => "id",
"artikel_nr" => "artikelnummer",
"ean_nr" => "eannummer",
"bezeichnung_1" => "bezeichnung",
"bezeichnung_2" => "bezeichnung_zusatz",
"match_code" => "matchcode",
"verkauf_me" => "mengeneinheit",
"gewicht" => "gewicht",
"lieferant_nr" => "hersteller_nummer",
"bestell_nr" => "hersteller_artikelnummer",
"produkt_gruppe" => "gruppe",
"artikel_gruppe" => "gruppe_nummer",
"produkt_hauptgruppe" => "hauptgruppe",
"rt_1" => "langtext",
"masse" => "dimension",
"einzelpreis_vk" => "listenpreis_netto"
}

count = 0
buffer = []

puts "starting import"

hersteller = Hash[CSV.read("db/red1.csv", col_sep: ',', row_sep: :auto, headers: true).map {|row| [row["lieferant_nr"], row["beschreibung"]]}]

CSV.foreach("db/red1.csv", col_sep: ',', row_sep: :auto, headers: true) do |row|
# map keys
 hash = Hash[row.map {|k, v| mapping[k] ? [mapping[k], v && v.strip.gsub("\u00A0", "")] : nil}.compact]

  # ignore NULL values
  hash.reject! {|k, v| v == "NULL"}

  # get hersteller names
  hash["hersteller"] = hersteller[hash["hersteller_nummer"]].strip.gsub("\u00A0", "")   if hash["hersteller_nummer"].present?

  # set hierarchie
  hash["hierarchie"] = if hash["hauptgruppe"].present? && hash["gruppe"].present?
                     "|" + hash["hauptgruppe"].strip + "|" + hash["gruppe"].strip
                   else
                     "|"
                   end

  # TODO: validate

  # enqueue hash
  buffer << hash

  count += 1
   if count % 1000 == 0
  Article.index.import buffer
  buffer = []

  puts count
 end
end

Article.index.import buffer unless buffer.empty?
puts count

puts "refresh index"

Article.index.refresh
```

my article,rb looks like

article.rb

```
property :artikelnummer, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'
property :eannummer, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'

 property :bezeichnung, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
bezeichnung: {type: 'string'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'},
suggest: {:type => 'string', :analyzer => 'suggest_analyzer'}
```

}

```
  property :bezeichnung_zusatz, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
bezeichnung_zusatz: {type: 'string'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
```

}

```
  property :matchcode, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'

  property :mengeneinheit, type: 'string', include_in_all: false

  property :gewicht, type: 'float', include_in_all: false

  property :hersteller, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
hersteller: {type: 'string'},
unchanged: {type: 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
```

}

```
     property :hersteller_nummer, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed', include_in_all: false

  property :hersteller_artikelnummer, type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'

  property :gruppe, type: 'multi_field', fields: {
gruppe: {type: 'string'},
ngram: {:type => 'string', :index_analyzer => 'ngram_index_analyzer', :search_analyzer => 'ngram_search_analyzer'}
  }
```

this stucture i have to use to create table

Comment: what does `Article.index.import` do, is that a special method you created??

Comment: I  m using elastic search  so why indexing..

Comment: seed is not supposed to create db tables. It is what migrate is for. Run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

Comment: @MarekLipka there isnt any migration file..I have structure in article.rb

Comment: So you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @MarekLipka see may edits